# Where can I programmatically set height of Outlook FormRegion?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I'm creating an Outlook 2007 plugin and adding controls on the fly so I need to set the height of the parent `FormRegion` programmatically.  I'm running into an issue where sometimes the `FormRegion` is changing its unit of measurement for the height or something to that effect.  When I try to programmatically set the height of the FormRegion (`this.Height = XXX`) within the `FormRegionShowing` event it winds up being screwed up because it's adjusted the unit of measure by a factor of roughly .41.

To reproduce this all I have to do is create a new Outlook 2007 plugin project, add a new "Adjoining" `FormRegion` to the project and add message boxes or some other debugging method to the following events (sometimes you have to double-click the outlook message and open in its own window):

```
private void FormRegion1_FormRegionShowing(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("FormRegionShowing: " + this.Height.ToString());
}

private void FormRegion1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("SizeChanged: " + this.Height.ToString());
}
```

I've tried debugging about every event I can think of but I've yet to find one that fires only once after the `FormRegionShowing`.  Do you know of a property or event I can use to make sure I'm setting the height properly?

For now my workaround is to capture the original height in `InitializeComponents`, then in the `FormRegionShowing` event get the conversion ratio and use it accordingly.  However this isn't ideal IMO.